# How to solve npmstart command error on my react project?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've got an error just like below when I ran a command `npm start`.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-16T04_34_53_206Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop>
```

Comment: It appears like you might be in the wrong folder make sure you cd into your folder before running npm start